# Passing adapter text to fragment creating problems

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to pass data to fragment so when items in recycler adapter clicked it pass item name (sample[position].text1) fetched from firebase  to fragment. I tried bundle, interface but getting error in both methods.I searched on internet but not find anything which solve my problem. mainActivity(splash screen) is only Activity in my App rest are fragments.

I used inner class method, I'm getting result but in another fragment where this adapter attached and I don't want it there.
**Problem:** pass sample[position].text1 to fragment so I can pass it to db.collection("here") to fetch data from Firebase.

Adapter

```
class dashboard_gridlayout_adapter(
private val sampledata: ArrayList<daxhboard_gridlayout_data>
): Adapter<dashboard_gridlayout_adapter.dashboard_viewholder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): dashboard_viewholder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.dashboard_gridlayout_single_item_design, parent, false)
    return dashboard_viewholder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: dashboard_viewholder, position: Int) {

    Glide.with(holder.itemView).load(sampledata[position].imageResource)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_history_icon)
            .into(holder.imageView)


    holder.textView.text = sampledata[position].text1
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val appCompatActivity = it.context as AppCompatActivity
        appCompatActivity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.Activity_frag_container, service_providers_list())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
    }
}

override fun getItemCount() = sampledata.size

inner class dashboard_viewholder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val imageView: ImageView = itemView.dashboard_adapter_image
    val textView: TextView = itemView.dashboard_adapter_text

}
}
```

Fragment

```
class service_providers_list : Fragment(){

private var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
private lateinit var service_list_recycler: RecyclerView
var servlist = ArrayList<service_provider_list_data>()


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_providers_list, container, false)
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        getserviceproviderdata()
        service_list_recycler = service_provider_recycle_view.findViewById(R.id.service_provider_recycle_view)
        service_provider_recycle_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.requireContext())
        service_provider_recycle_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
    }


    private fun getserviceproviderdata() {

        db.collection("Barber").orderBy("dist")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                    servlist.clear()
                    for (document in documents) {

                        val imgurl = document.data["imageResource"].toString()
                        val prov_name = document.data["provider_name"].toString()
                        val prov_address = document.data["provider_address"].toString()
                        val prov_rate = document.data["provider_rating"].toString()
                        val prov_dist = document.data["provider_distance"].toString()

                        servlist.add(service_provider_list_data(imgurl, prov_name, prov_address, prov_rate, prov_dist))
                        service_provider_recycle_view.adapter = service_provider_list_adapter(servlist)
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Log.e("serf", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
                }
    }
}
```

MainActivity (It's a splash screen)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

   
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    Handler().postDelayed(
        {

            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Activity_frag_container,Login_Screen()).commit()
        },
        1500
    )

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem

just add new parameter(need to pass) inside replace in adapter

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val datashares = sampledata[position].text1
        val appCompatActivity = it.context as AppCompatActivity
        appCompatActivity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.Activity_frag_container, service_providers_list(datashares))
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()

    }
```

and inside fragment just add

```
class service_providers_list(datashares: String) Fragment(){
  //variable declaration
   private var datasharae = datashares

 (inside function where i wnt to add code i.e getserviceproviderdata() )

  fun getserviceproviderdata() {

        db.collection(datasharae)
     .............
    ..............
    ......rest code.....
    .........}
```